# 'variable1 / variable2 = NaN' where both variables are the number 2

Tags: javascript, variables, division

I am at a loss as to what to do here, in the process of trying to figure this out myself I printed this out (in CMD):

```
testData.topics[z].percentageMark :2
testData.topics[z].questions.length :2
typeof(testData.topics[z].percentageMark) :number
typeof (testData.topics[z].questions.length) :number
FINAL : testData.topics[z].percentageMark :NaN
```

This was a result of the code (sorry about the large objects):

```
console.log("testData.topics[z].percentageMark :" + testData.topics[z].percentageMark);
console.log("testData.topics[z].questions.length :" + testData.topics[z].questions.length);
console.log("typeof(testData.topics[z].percentageMark) :" + typeof (testData.topics[z].percentageMark));
console.log("typeof (testData.topics[z].questions.length) :" + typeof (testData.topics[z].questions.length));
testData.topics[z].percentageMark = ((testData.topics[z].percentageMarks) / (testData.topics[z].questions.length));
console.log("FINAL : testData.topics[z].percentageMark :" + testData.topics[z].percentageMark);
```

I am truly baffled as to what to do here, I cannot see how a simple division here would not work.

Comment: 5th line of code ... `percentageMarks` !== `percentageMark`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo here

> (testData.topics[z].percentageMarks)

"percentageMarks"

For the record, you may as well write `var topic = testData.topics[z]`

problems like yours are only easier when you have very long lines of code.

You can also align your code for ease of reading.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo error,`percentageMarks` should be `percentageMark`. `testData.topics[z].percentageMarks` is `undefined` and when you divide the `undefined` by a number, you get `NaN`.

So, Change the code from

```
testData.topics[z].percentageMark = ((testData.topics[z].percentageMarks) / (testData.topics[z].questions.length));
```

to

```
testData.topics[z].percentageMark = ((testData.topics[z].percentageMark) / (testData.topics[z].questions.length));
```